# How can I install centreon/centreon?

Tags: 8, updating

My website is built with Drupal 8.3.2. I want to update to to Drupal 8.9.x, but I don't want to move to Drupal 9.x. I ran the following command.

```bash
composer update drupal/core-recommended:8.9 --with-dependencies
```

I am getting these errors. The site uses PHP 7.3.33.

> Could not load package centreon/centreon in http://repo.packagist.org: [UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint optimize-browser-configuration-dev: Invalid version string "optimize-browser-configuration-dev"

I tried to install centreon/centreon, but there is no package.

Can anybody help me with resolving this issue?

This is the content of the *composer.json* file used for the site.

```json
{
    "name": "drupal/drupal",
    "description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0+",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.9",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4"
    },
    "replace": {
        "drupal/core": "^8.3"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
    },
    "extra": {
        "_readme": [
            "By default Drupal loads the autoloader from ./vendor/autoload.php.",
            "To change the autoloader you can edit ./autoload.php.",
            "This file specifies the packages.drupal.org repository.",
            "You can read more about this composer repository at:",
            "https://www.drupal.org/node/2718229"
        ],
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "core/composer.json"
            ],
            "recurse": false,
            "replace": false,
            "merge-extra": false
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
            "modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
            "themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal\Core/Composer"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
        "post-autoload-dump": [
          "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess"
        ],
        "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
        "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What's the output of `composer why centreon/centreon`?

Comment: [InvalidArgumentException]                                  
  Could not find package "centreon/centreon" in your project

Comment: So you have a ghost package somewhere.  Assuming you have backed up everything, delete `composer.lock` and the entire `vendor` folder; then try composer update again.

Comment: I tried but same issue again...                                                                                                                   
  Could not load package centreon/centreon in http://repo.packagist.org:

Comment: If you're on linux or macOS, try grepping the directory that contains the codebase: `grep "centreon" * -r`

Comment: Also it looks like it may be this module, which appears abandoned: https://www.drupal.org/project/centreon_status  If you have that module, I would uninstall it, remove it from the codebase, and then to update try again.

Comment: There is no such module in my code base , I am using linux machine. I verified for word "centreon" but nothing found in code base.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134719/discussion-between-patrick-kenny-and-user3463733).

Comment: Try `composer clear-cache`

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps to resolve issue.

**Step 1 : Downgrade Composer to 1.10.9**

composer self-update 1.10.9

**Step 2 : Run below command**

composer require drupal/pathauto:^1.6

**Step 3 : Run below command**

composer remove --dev webflo/drupal-core-require-dev

**Step 4 : Run below command**

composer require --update-with-dependencies 
drupal/core:^8.8 
symfony/finder:^3.4 
symfony/filesystem:^3.4

**Step 5 : Run below command**

composer require --dev --update-with-dependencies 
drupal/core-dev:^8.8 
symfony/debug:^3.4

**Step 6 : Run below Command**

composer remove -n 
symfony/finder 
symfony/filesystem 
symfony/debug

**Step 7 : Run below command**

drush updb

**Step 8 : Run below command**

drush cr

**Step 9 : Update settings.php**

In Drupal 8.8.0 the sync directory is defined in $settings and not $config_directories, and so the Settings.php file should be updated.

change from:

$config_directories['sync'] = 'foo/bar';

to

$settings['config_sync_directory'] = 'foo/bar';